# How can I append templates to form container

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, adminhtml

I have a block that extends `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container`.

I also have two blocks of type `core/template` that use template files that I'd like to include within my main form.

Is it possible to add these templates as children of the form and render them after everything else?

I'm trying to prevent having to write a bunch of html when I can use the blocks form building functions.

Here's my layout section:

```
<adminhtml_onsite_purchaseorder_edit>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><file>darkhorse/simplemde/simplemde.min.js</file></action>
        <action method="addCss"><file>darkhorse/onsite/simplemde/simplemde.min.css</file></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="onsite/adminhtml_purchaseOrder_edit">
            <block type="core/template" template="darkhorse/purchaseOrder/items.phtml" name="purchaseOrder_items" as="purchaseOrder_items" />
            <block type="core/template" template="darkhorse/purchaseOrder/notes.phtml" name="purchaseOrder_notes" as="purchaseOrder_notes" />
        </block>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_onsite_purchaseorder_edit>
```

Block:

```
class Darkhorse_Onsite_Block_Adminhtml_PurchaseOrder_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_objectId = 'id';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_purchaseOrder';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'onsite';
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('onsite')->__('Save Purchase Order'));
        $this->removeButton('delete');
        $this->removeButton('back');
        $this->removeButton('reset');

        $this->_formScripts[] = '
            function saveAndContinueEdit(){
                editForm.submit($("edit_form").action+"back/edit/");
            }
        ';
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve text for header element depending on loaded page
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getHeaderText()
    {
         if (Mage::registry('current_purchaseOrder')->getId()) {
            return $this->escapeHtml(Mage::registry('current_purchaseOrder')->getName());
        } else {
            return Mage::helper('onsite')->__('New PurchaseOrder');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Prepare layout
     *
     * @return Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->_addButton('save_and_continue', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('onsite')->__('Save and Continue Edit'),
            'onclick'   => 'saveAndContinueEdit(\''.$this->_getSaveAndContinueUrl().'\')',
            'class'     => 'save'
        ), 10);

        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    protected function _getSaveAndContinueUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array(
            '_current'  => true,
            'back'      => 'edit',
            'tab'       => '{{tab_id}}',
            'active_tab'=> null,
        ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally... I've come up with a solution and so far it seems to work fairly well.

What I did was changed `setUseContainer(true)` to `setUseContainer(false)`.

Doing that allowed me to remove the `<form>` tags. Now I on the form block I can override the function `_toHtml()`

Here's that function now:

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    $html = '<form ' . $this->_form->serialize($this->_form->getHtmlAttributes()) . '>';
    $html .= '<div>';
    if (strtolower($this->_form->getData('method')) == 'post') {
        $html .= '<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="'.Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey().'" />';
    }
    $html .= '</div>';
    return $html.parent::_toHtml().$this->getChildHtml('items').'</form>';
}
```

As you can see I added a protected variable named `$_form`. This variable is set to the form that I created in `_prepareForm()`.

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this, but for me it works fantastically. It allows me to insert templates straight into a single page admin form.